# Make Safari 5's location bar more like Omnibox or AwesomeBar

Tags: macos, safari

When searching for history or favorites, the search phrase has to be an exact substring of the URL or title. For example `super awesome` wouldn't match this page. Can the criteria be made more liberal?

When an item that was matched by its title is selected from the suggestion list, the title is filled in in place of the URL. The filled in part sometimes starts from the middle of a URL or a title. Can either of these behaviors be changed?

Can you redirect unresolved addresses to the default search engine or a custom URL? In Firefox you can go to `about:config` and set `keyword.URL` to `http://www.google.com/search?btnI&q=`.

Can you remove or hide the web search field? In Camino, Cruz, and Fluid it can be resized to zero width.

Comment: Please note this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Asking a zillion questions in a single post is not really useful here, I think.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Safari Keyword Search](http://safarikeywordsearch.aurlien.net/) (Safari extension)

[image]

- Unresolved URLs can be redirected to Google web search

#### [SafariOmnibar](https://github.com/rs/SafariOmnibar) (SIMBL plugin)

- Hides the web search field
- Unresolved URLs can be redirected to Google web search

#### [Search Safari History](http://support.alfredapp.com/extensions:web) (Alfred extension)

[image]

- Search phrases don't have to match the URL or title exactly

Comment: cooool... hope this replaces the Stand below! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that fixes all of them, but [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) does much of it and provides workarounds for some of the others (e.g. focus search field instead of location).

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned you have tried many extensions... Have you tried [Safari Stand](https://web.archive.org/web/20110216063540/http://www.pimpmysafari.com/plugins/safaristand)?

I'm only linking another site rather than the [official one](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511130148/http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) because you can also find more stuff there, in case any of those are new for you. It's not omnibar but to me it's enough. I'm not sure if it answers all your points, but at very least you can use keywords to trigger different URL / searches.